# Javascript console.log yields [object Object] result

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have an Ajax call that returns a JSON-encoded array. When I `console.log()` the data I received, I get exactly what I expected - a string representation of an array. However, when I `JSON.parse()` this string and then try to `console.log()` the result, I get a series of `[object Object]`. Why is that?

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function shout(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
}

//Ajax call returns string JsonData

shout("jsonData is "+jsonData); //Produces the string-representation of my array
var parsedData=JSON.parse(jsonData);
shout("parsedData is "+parsedData); //Produces a series of [object Object]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your parsed JSON contains objects, and they have a string representation of `[object Object]` -- try `console.log([{},{}] + "")` to see what I mean.

Comment: Because it's not a string anymore, it's now an object literal.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli—just an object.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli - an object literal is a language construct, not a runtime entity. Your comment makes no sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an object now, so you access the properties like any object. I have no idea what's supposed to be in your object, but you get the idea.

```
for (var i = 0; i < parsedData.length; i++) {
    shout(parsedData[i].property1);
    shout(parsedData[i].property2);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ah, OK. I was hoping for `console.log()` to act roughly like `var_dump()` in php. I guess I was wrong...  :-)

Answer (score 2):

The reason that you are seeing this message "parsedData is [object Object]" is because JavaScript is concatenating the string + casting the object into a single concatenated string, before it appends it to that string. It casts the object into a string of the object's type, but as you know it isn't displaying the object's contents. Console.log can't be used to render out a string + an object in that manner, without JSON.stringify().

To get your code to work, try this:

```
shout("parsedData is " + JSON.stringify(parsedData));
```

Here is how it works:

```
<script>
  function shout(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
  }

  //Ajax call returns string JsonData
  var jsonData = '{"a":"abc","b":"cool beans","c":"xyz"}';

  shout("jsonData is " + jsonData); //Produces the string-representation of my array
  var parsedData = JSON.parse(jsonData);
  shout("parsedData is " + parsedData); //Produces a series of [object Object]
  shout("JSON.stringify(parsedData) is " + JSON.stringify(parsedData));

  // The JSON.stringify function, essentially does this:
  var output = '{';
  for (var key in parsedData) {
    output += '"' + key + '":"' + parsedData[key] + '",';
  }
  output += '}';
  output = output.replace(',}','}');
  shout("output is " + output);
</script>
```

The output looks like this:

```
jsonData is {"a":"abc","b":"cool beans","c":"xyz"}
parsedData is [object Object]
JSON.stringify(parsedData) is {"a":"abc","b":"cool beans","c":"xyz"}
output is {"a":"abc","b":"cool beans","c":"xyz"}
```

Btw, we don't need to use the type="text/javascript" attribute in the script tags anymore. Less typing = Cool beans! Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(msg))
```

If this does not work, please provide part of the server-side code so we can help.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11586334)

Comment: @BennyBottema It does. If this was to be reworded to _"try to log it with `JSON.stringify` instead"_ there would be no doubt that it is an answer.

Comment: The problem with this type of answer is that it often is more of a checklist item rather than a definite answer. Instead, if you were to respond this in comment and it turns out to be the solution, then you can provide it as an answer. Seeing your reputation prevents you from commenting, I can understand that's a problem right now. A definitive answer would be a working solution in a code snippet using the proposed solution, instead if "try this" to see how far we come.

Comment: @BennyBottema I apologize if this was not the right way to post. I was just trying to help, as I have run into this issue several times, and this is how I fixed it. I truly believe that my answer is the correct one, but I guess the asker didn't feel the same way.

Answer (score 0):

When you append an object to a string it calls `toString` on the object. For example:

```
console.log('hey ' + { a: 1 }); // 'hey [object Object]'
```

If you want to have a string followed by an actual object, you can pass the object as another argument to `console.log`:

```
console.log('hey', { a: 1 }); // 'hey' Object {a: 1}
```